# Powershell : Remove Info from Get-WinEvent Returned Results

Tags: string, powershell

Running the following

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $env:ComputerName -LogName Application | Where {$_.ID -eq 63} | Select-Object -Unique
```

Results are as follows

```
ProviderName: Outlook

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message                                                                                                                                 
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------                                                                                                                                 
10/17/2014 10:09:04 AM          63 Information      The Exchange web service request GetAppManifests succeeded.
```

How can I remove or strip out the following

```
ProviderName: Outlook

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message                                                                                                                                 
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
```

So that I am just left with

```
10/17/2014 10:09:04 AM          63 Information      The Exchange web service request GetAppManifests succeeded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe your output to Format-Table:

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $env:ComputerName -LogName Application `
    | Where {$_.ID -eq 63} | Select-Object -Unique `
    | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

And if you want to convert the output to string, you can further pipe to `Out-String`.